# Limit where wolfram alpha does not help

Tags: limits, summation

With the help of [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi%3Dx%2B1%7D%5E%7Boo%7D%20q%5Ei%20%2ai%20%2F%20%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bx%7D%20%28q%29%5Ei%20%2a%20i) I got the following
$$\frac{\sum_{i=x+1}^{\infty} i q^i}{\sum_{i=1}^x i q^i}=\frac{q^x (x(1-q))+1}{q^x (x(q-1)-1)+1}$$

Now I am intersted in the behavior of this sum for $0<q<1$ a constant and $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Here, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit_%7Bx-%3E%20oo%7D%20%28q%5Ex%20%28-q%20x%2Bx%2B1%29%29%2F%28x%20q%5E%28x%2B1%29-%28x%2B1%29%20q%5Ex%2B1%29%20) does not help.

By dividing by $q^x$ I get:
$$\frac{x(1-q)+q^{-x}}{x(q-1)-1+q^{-x}}\rightarrow 1$$
Is this true?

Comment: Don't you means to say $|q|<1$. Otherwise your argument won't make much sense with merely $q<1$.

Comment: @Gina thank you. that is what i meant. $0<q<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\sum_{i=1}^x iq^i \to \sum_{i=1}^\infty iq^i = q/(1-q)^2$, and hence, as this sum converges, $\sum_{i=x+1}^\infty iq^i \to 0$, $x\to\infty$.

That gives $$ \frac{\sum_{i=x+1}^\infty iq^i}{\sum_{i=1}^x iq^i} \to 0 $$
Note that [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi%3Dx%2B1%7D%5E%7Boo%7D%20q%5Ei%20%2ai%20%2F%20%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bx%7D%20%28q%29%5Ei%20%2a%20i) gives you
$$ \frac{\sum_{i=x+1}^\infty iq^i}{\sum_{i=1}^x iq^i}  = \frac{q^x(-qx+x+1)}{xq^{x+1} -(x+1)q^x + 1} \to 0 $$
(you missed one paranthesis).